# Using Html Agility Pack to select all paragraphs that start with a certain text value

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am learning to use the Html Agility Pack.

I have a series of paragraph elements that look like this (code split for clarity):

```
<p class="rvps2">
    <img alt="New Version Icon" 
         style="vertical-align: middle; padding : 1px; margin : 0px 5px;"
         src="lib/IMG_NewVersion.png">
    <span class="rvts16">Version 21.1.0 - 2021 Edition</span>
    <span class="rvts15"> (22nd March 2021)</span>
</p>
```

I am only interested in the paragraphs that start with the text "Version". At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
// Select all Paragraph elements
var nodesParagraph = nodeRevHist.SelectNodes("p");

int iRevisionCount = 0;
foreach (HtmlNode itemParagraph in nodesParagraph)
{
    string text = itemParagraph.InnerText;
    if (text.Length > 7 && text.Substring(0, 7) == "Version")
    {
        iRevisionCount++;
```

Is it possible for `nodesParagraph` to be filtered to all paragraphs where the inner text starts with "Version"?

This would make my code cleaner if it is possible. Side question, I am also only interested in the first 5 of these paragraph elements.

Is this filtering possible?

Comment: Do you really need to do the length and substring checks yourself? `text.StartsWith("Version ")` wouldn't allocate a new string every time and would return false if `text` is too short.

Comment: @madreflection Awesome. I am more familiar with C++ and did not notice that method in the list. Thanks.

Comment: There's also the `Contains` method, `text.Contains("Version")`

Comment: If the `rvts16` class is unique to those paragraphs, though, you should see if you can filter on that, first.

Comment: @madreflection I don't want to rely on the class names because they are provided by HelpNDoc when I build my help files. So those class names might change. I have already isolated the correct `div` element in the file and I am following a strict pattern for my history content. So I think I am safe using this approach.

Comment: If they're generated, then you're right, you don't want to rely on them. Use the 'Contains' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first 5 paragraphs where the inner text starts with "Version" like this:

```
var nodesParagraph = nodeRevHist
    .Elements("p")
    .Where(p => p.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("Version"))
    .Take(5);
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvwcUN

Comment: Thank you. Am I right in saying that this is guaranteed to create a variable, even if empty? Or is it still wise to wrap it in a `try` / `catch` block?

Comment: I did some experimenting with this.  If there are no `p` elements in `nodeRevHist` then `SelectNodes` returns null, which makes the `Where` clause blow up.  But if you switch to using the `Elements` method instead of `SelectNodes`, then it works, assuming `nodeRevHist` itself is not null.  So you would definitely need a null check to guard against that.  A try/catch would be safest if you are unsure of the input.