# Is there a simpler way to re-format this date as a short date in c#?

Tags: c#, date, html-agility-pack

Given this code:

```
// Decode the text string
string test = "Version 21.1.0 - 2021 Edition (22nd March 2021)";
string[] textitems = test.Split(' ');

// The text should split down like this:

// [0] Version
// [1] 21.1.0
// [2] -
// [3] 2021
// [4] Edition
// [5] (22nd
// [6] March
// [7] 2021)
```

I have created a `enum` to use:

```
enum UpdateInfo
{
    Version = 1,
    Edition = 3,
    Day = 5,
    Month = 6,
    Year = 7
}
```

The information I am interested in is:

- Version Number:  21.1.0
- Edition: 2021
- Date: (22nd March 2021)

`Version` and `Edition` are straightforward:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Version]);
writer.WriteAttributeString("Edition", textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Edition]);
```

But the `Date` is not. I found out that I can't parse (eg.):

```
(22nd March 2021)
```

I want the **short date** so I have come up with the following code after doing research:

```
// Rebuild date as short date

// Day - strip off "(" and "st", "nd", "rd" or "th"
string day = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Day].Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Day][i]))
        day += textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Day][i];
}

// Rebuilt long date
string datetest = day + " " + textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Month] + " " + textitems[(int)UpdateInfo.Year];

// Remove trailing ")"
datetest = datetest.Trim(')');

// Now we can parse the long date string
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetest, "d MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

if (date != null)
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", date.ToShortDateString());
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result without bloating the code?

---

Note:

- The dates will always be in **English**.
- The source data is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66790026/2287576). Eg:

```
<p class="rvps2">
    <img alt="New Version Icon" 
         style="vertical-align: middle; padding : 1px; margin : 0px 5px;"
         src="lib/IMG_NewVersion.png">
    <span class="rvts16">Version 21.1.0 - 2021 Edition</span>
    <span class="rvts15"> (22nd March 2021)</span>
</p>
```

So I actually have a `HtmlNode` (the `p` element`).

Comment: `enum` is not needed, unless you have state machine in parsing value logic. Your case is a good candidate to learn regex.

Comment: Sorry, my brain bugged after the enum declaration. Why an enum? A struct or a class, I would understand, but enum, I don't...

Comment: @Antoine That is from my MFC / C++ background where I am used to creating `enum` objects that return `int` without cast (unless using the `class` approach).

Comment: @Andrew Ok, I see it now. Brain unbugged, continue reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not split by spaces, there are too many. I would split by `"-"` and then use regex to extract the date part. Then it's easy with `TryParseExact` and `dd'nd' MMMM yyyy`:

```
string[] textitems = test.Split('-');
string version = textitems[0].Trim();
string edition = textitems[1].Substring(0, textitems[1].IndexOf("(")).Trim();
string dateStr = Regex.Match(textitems[1], @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;

string[] formats = { "d'st' MMMM yyyy", "d'nd' MMMM yyyy" };
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date );
```

I have added also `d'st' MMMM yyyy` since i can imagine that this would be your next issue. Another option was to include the brackets in the format: `"'('d'nd' MMMM yyyy')'"`.

You might want to add some code to validate the input first, i have omitted that.

Comment: Thanks, but it might be nd, st, rd, th.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: befor you commented i have edited my answer. You can add more valid formats in that array.

Comment: I have to get my head around that regex statement.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I'm also not a regex expert, it just means "give me everything between the round brackets".

Comment: I can’t test right now but version should be 21.1.0. I can’t see how that is obtained from the first code line? I will check when home.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Ok, if you dont't want the text "Version" in it just split the first part again and then with space. Then it's the secoond token. Or, if it's always the string literal "Version", you can simply remove it: `textitems[0].Trim().Substring(8)`

Comment: Out of interest could the format strings simply include the brackets like it does the nd etc.?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: good idea, yes, that would work as well: `"'('d'nd' MMMM yyyy')'"`

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I "understand" it better. However, I am going to add a third answer which combines both answers provided so far.

Answer (score 2):

For this I wouldn't even bother with splitting the text, you can do this with a regular expression and named matches.

```
string test = "Version 21.1.0 - 2021 Edition (22nd August 2021)";
var regex = new Regex(@"Version (?'version'[\d.]+) - (?'edition'\d+) Edition \((?'date'[^)]+)", RegexOptions.None);
var matches = regex.Matches(test);

var version = matches[0].Groups["version"].Value;
var edition = matches[0].Groups["edition"].Value;
var dateString = matches[0].Groups["date"].Value;

// remove date ordinal before parsing
dateString = Regex.Replace(dateString, @"^(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)", "$1");
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

date.ToShortDateString().Dump();
```

Normally I would use `TryParseExact` and handle any parse exceptions properly.

You can get an explanation of the main regular expression here: https://regex101.com/r/Nzpa5h/1

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you. I confess that I struggle to understand what the regex is doing and I like to use code I can get my head around. This is why I accepted the other answer. However, I am going to add a third answer with my final code and I would still like clarification about the regex I have used.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution that combines both approaches. Since the original data is actually a `HtmlNode` (as indicated at the bottom of the question) and is already split into two `span` elements, I decided to do it this way:

```
// The paragraph element should only have two "span" elements
var listSpan = itemParagraph.Descendants("span");
if(listSpan != null)
{
    if(listSpan.Count() == 2)
    {
        // The first "span" element should contain: Version 21.1.0 - 2021 Edition
        var regex = new Regex(@"Version (?'version'[\d.]+) - (?'edition'\d+) Edition", RegexOptions.None);
        var matches = regex.Matches(listSpan.ElementAt(0).InnerText.Trim());

        writer.WriteStartElement("Update");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", matches[0].Groups["version"].Value);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Edition", matches[0].Groups["edition"].Value);

        // The second "span" element should contain: eg. (22nd March 2021)
        string dateString = listSpan.ElementAt(1).InnerText.Trim(' ', '(', ')');

        string[] formats =
        {
            "d'st' MMMM yyyy",
            "d'nd' MMMM yyyy",
            "d'rd' MMMM yyyy",
            "d'th' MMMM yyyy"
        };

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,
            formats, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateRevision))
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", dateRevision.ToShortDateString());
        }
    }
}
```

I admit that I do not quite follow how this bit of code actually works:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Version (?'version'[\d.]+) - (?'edition'\d+) Edition", RegexOptions.None);
var matches = regex.Matches(listSpan.ElementAt(0).InnerText.Trim());
```

The above code is modified from one of the supplied answers. But it works. :)

I decided to construct the date using the accepted answer approach as I understand what it is doing, as opposed to the regex suggestion.

@phuzi maybe you could add some explanations or pointers to flesh out your answer concerning the regex syntax?